# How does email not addressed to me get routed to my mailbox?

Tags: email, mail-server

I've been seeing email that's not directly addressed to me land up in my inbox.

My email is `something@domain.com`, the emails that are delivered are like `something+anything@domain.com`. After seeing these, I tried other suffixes after the `+` symbol and all of them land up in my inbox. Does anyone know why that is the case? What happens if someone else registers one of the addresses like `something+1@domain.com`.

I saw this reliably work for both `gmail` and `outlook`, I'm curious to know why that is the case? Is there is a technical reason why `mailservers` drop off these suffixes.

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the best place for this question, please move this to another site on the network which may be a better fit if that is the case.

Comment: Is your domain.com a mailserver like google, or an individual company email server?

Comment: I tested these with my public emails, google and outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called sub-addressing. + part is treated for filtering and all.You can read about it on wiki  with page title Email Address.

> Also known as plus  addressing ortagged addressing. Some mail services support a tag appended to the local part, such that the modified address is an alias to the unmodified address. For example, the address joeuser+tag@example.com denotes the same delivery address asjoeuser@example.com.